# Image Available on Sentinel Open Access Hub but not available on GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, sentinel-2

I downloaded a Sentinel-2 image from Sentinel Open Access Hub. This image is available offline in Sentinel Open Access Hub, which I added to my cart and downloaded.
However, when I try to access the image on Google Earth Engine (GEE) using:

```js
var s2_flood = ee.Image("COPERNICUS/S2/20221031T094039_20221031T123138_T32PPU");
print(s2_flood);
var imgDisplay = {min:0.0, max: 1500, bands: ['B4','B3','B2']};
```

I got the following error:

```
Image (Error)
Image.load: Image asset 'COPERNICUS/S2/20221031T094039_20221031T123138_T32PPU' not found (does not exist or caller does not have access).
```

I am curious why this image is not available on GEE.

Comment: The image_id provided for the ee.Image() is wrong. It will be either "COPERNICUS/S2_SR_HARMONIZED/20221031T094039_20221031T123138_T32PPU" or "COPERNICUS/S2_HARMONIZED/20221031T094039_20221031T123138_T32PPU" for Surface Reflectance and TOA data respectively. However, I have tested and the image is still showing unavailable. You can manually try getting the image using date and bounds filter.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.

I later found out that the name/identifier of the image was different in GEE.
 
I had to use "ee.ImageCollection()" to filter the sentinel-2 scenes for the study region and dates that I was looking for. That's when I realized that the identifier was slightly different from the one I downloaded from Sentinel Open Access Hub.